# Prolog / true false definition

Tags: prolog

So, im working with this following code:

```
test:- p(X,Y), r(Y), s(X), write(X), nl, fail.
test.

test2(X,Y):- p(X,Y), r(Y).

p(3,4).
p(6,9).
p(7,8).

r(X):- s(X), t(X).

s(7).
s(6):-!.
s(8).

t(9).
t(8).
t(5):-!.
t(4).
```

`s(X)` returns `X=7;X=6.`

`t(X)` returns `X=9;X=8;X=5.`

Obviously, `r(X)` returns `false`.

My question is, how the hell then `test2(X,Y)` returns `X=7,Y=8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r(X)` will fail... but `r(8)` will not! This is because if you use `r(X)`, the system searches until it encounters the `!` operator, then stops searching. But if you ask it for `r(8)` directly, it will never encounter the `!` operator in the first place.

So when the system unifies `p(X,Y)` with `p(7,8)`, the next step is to try `r(8)`, which leads to `s(8), t(8)`.  Both of these succeed, because they look for `s(8)` and `t(8)`, rather than `s(X)` and `t(X)`. So they don't encounter the `!` operator. The result is that `r(8)` evaluates to true, eventually leading to X=7, Y=8.

Guess it illustrates how careful one must be when using `!`.

Comment: That's actually hilarious that it will look first for r(8)... Thank you very much, you just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: You're welcome! It looks for `r(8)` first because it's already unified Y=8 at that point. If the rule was `r(Y), p(X,Y)` then it would fail. Sometimes I think the full name of `!` should be `use_carefully!` :-)

Comment: @Ironwing *...hilarious that it will look first for `r(8)`...*. Actually, Prolog doesn't do this. When you query in Prolog, it searches starting at the beginning of your asserted facts and predicates for a term that the query will unify with. When you query `r(X)`, Prolog is able to unify `r(X)` with `r(6)` yielding `X = 6`, and then it backtracks and can unify `r(X)` with `r(7)` yielding `X = 7`, but then the cut prevents further backtracking. When you query `r(8)`, Prolog fails to unify it with `r(6)` or `r(7)`, never gets to the cut in `r(7) :- !` and finally succeeds unifying with `r(8).`